# MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, root

While connecting to mysql through 'root' user, I am getting the mentioned error.
Commands tried:

```
mysql (as by default it takes root user)
mysql -u root -p
```

I Tried putting the root credentials in "/etc/my.cnf" file, but no luck.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Note: All credit to this answer goes to [Netaji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103872/netaji) and you can found his answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818827/mysql-error-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password)

my problem was solved in below way.

When I was entered below command then I will get an error. **sudo mysql -u root -p**

```
Enter password:   
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

To resolve this follow below steps.

1. enter command

   **sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & [4] 21878**

Then the below error occurred.

```
2018-12-17T06:43:33.106111Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2018-12-17T06:43:33.108971Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 152: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
2018-12-17T06:43:33.111388Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 152: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql//error.log: Permission denied
^C
[4]   Exit 1                  mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

To resolve this error, then follow below lines.

```
i) systemctl stop mysql

2018-12-17T06:48:42.971692Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2018-12-17T06:48:42.974451Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-12-17T06:48:42.976653Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

ii) sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld

iii) sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld

iv)sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

[5] 24203

2018-12-17T06:50:39.135292Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2018-12-17T06:50:39.137938Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-12-17T06:50:39.152966Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

v) Then connect mysql -u root.
```

then MySQL prompt will appear. then after set your password.

```
vi) FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

```
vi) systemctl stop mysql
```

vi) After that loing in below way.

```
   `mysql -u root -p`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your mysql root password

please follow these instructions : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you didn't describe you situation clearly. Is your mysql a new install, reinstall or upgrade? Or any operation you performed on root user?
 What is your mysql version? ...

Actually, there are many questions similar to your cases, have your tired their solution?

Answer (score 0):

First: You don't want to put your credentials in `/etc/my.cnf` but in `~/.my.cnf` (mind the leading dot). The contents of `.my.cnf` should look like this

```
[client]
user=USERNAME
pass=PASSWORD
```

If your password is correct, you should be able to login with just `mysql` without any options.

If that doesn't work and you are not able to login with

```
mysql -u root -pMYPASS
```

(mind the missing space between `-p` and the actual password), then you may have to reset the password.